# Android - java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout

Tags: debugging, android-studio, crash

I need help in *debugging* and *fixing* my app.

The *app* crashes when I click at `ok`.

Here is the part of the *source code* of the **ToDo activity**

```
public class ToDoActivity extends RealmBaseActivity {

private static final int[] COLORS = new int[] {
        Color.argb(255, 28, 160, 170),
        Color.argb(255, 99, 161, 247),
        Color.argb(255, 13, 79, 139),
        Color.argb(255, 89, 113, 173),
        Color.argb(255, 200, 213, 219),
        Color.argb(255, 99, 214, 74),
        Color.argb(255, 205, 92, 92),
        Color.argb(255, 105, 5, 98)
};

private Realm realm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.to_do_layout);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

  FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            buildAndShowInputDialog();
        }
    });

    resetRealm();
    realm = Realm.getInstance(getRealmConfig());
    RealmResults<TodoItem> toDoItems = realm
            .where(TodoItem.class)
            .findAllSorted("id", Sort.ASCENDING);
    ToDoRealmAdapter toDoRealmAdapter =
            new ToDoRealmAdapter(this, toDoItems, true, true);
    RealmRecyclerView realmRecyclerView =
            (RealmRecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.realm_recycler_view);
    realmRecyclerView.setAdapter(toDoRealmAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (realm != null) {
        realm.close();
        realm = null;
    }
}

private void buildAndShowInputDialog() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new
   AlertDialog.Builder(ToDoActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Create A Task");

    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View dialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.to_do_dialog_view, null);
    final EditText input = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.input);

    builder.setView(dialogView);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            addToDoItem(input.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
    input.setOnEditorActionListener(
            new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||
                            (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                                    event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        addToDoItem(input.getText().toString());
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
}

private void addToDoItem(String toDoItemText) {
    if (toDoItemText == null || toDoItemText.length() == 0) {
        Toast
                .makeText(this, "Empty ToDos don't get stuff done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return;
    }

    realm.beginTransaction();
    TodoItem todoItem = realm.createObject(TodoItem.class);
    todoItem.setId(System.currentTimeMillis());
    todoItem.setDescription(toDoItemText);
    realm.commitTransaction();
}

public class ToDoRealmAdapter
        extends RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter<TodoItem, ToDoRealmAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public class ViewHolder extends RealmViewHolder {

        public TextView todoTextView;
        public ViewHolder(FrameLayout container) {
            super(container);
            this.todoTextView = (TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.todo_text_view);
        }
    }

    public ToDoRealmAdapter(
            Context context,
            RealmResults<TodoItem> realmResults,
            boolean automaticUpdate,
            boolean animateResults) {
        super(context, realmResults, automaticUpdate, animateResults);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateRealmViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.to_do_item_view, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder((FrameLayout) v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindRealmViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        final TodoItem toDoItem = realmResults.get(position);
        viewHolder.todoTextView.setText(toDoItem.getDescription());
        viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(
                COLORS[(int) (toDoItem.getId() % COLORS.length)]
        );
    }
}
}
```

---

**EDIT**:

This is the error stack trace in the **logcat**:

[image]

**layout to_do_item_view**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/todo_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        />
 </FrameLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your question is *too broad*, could you please **edit** it explaining your attempts to *debug* it (did you narrow down the possible fault location?) and any eventual error message that you are provided (if any)?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I added screenshot of logcat

Comment: It says *"java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout"*, what are lines 164 and 141 in your *original* source code?

Comment: There are a number of related questions to your problem, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879184/java-lang-classcastexception-android-widget-linearlayoutlayoutparams-cannot-be . There are more involving different Layout classes.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin   line141:  public class ToDoRealmAdapter  line164;ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder((FrameLayout) v);

Comment: thus the problem is `inflater.inflate(R.layout.to_do_item_view, viewGroup, false);` yelds a *android.widget.LinearLayout*, did you check the arguments?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I checked them but I am confused is the problem in the imports or is it in the layout to_do_item_view? I posted the layout in the new edit

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I fixed the problem thank you for your patience with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by removing this from the layout above

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
```